# nginx-pache reverse proxy 403 error

Tags: apache, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, reverse-proxy

So I've decided to give reverse proxy a try, with apache being the 'back end' service.

It seemed like everything has been configured correctly, and I'v verified my settings with several guides online, however nginx returns a 403 error when trying to access "/var/www/"

My first inclination was to check permissions but thatdoesn't appear to the issue. Even after pushing the permissions to each directory\file I've got nothing changed.

Secondly I'm wondering if I have to set ownership of "/var/www/" to nginx's default user, but I'm not so sure about it.

Below I'll share nginx and apache's settings:

Here's the config for nginx /etc/nginx/sites-available/* -

```
server {
        listen   80; 

        root /var/www/; 
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com; 

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

         }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Here's the config for apache /etc/apache2/sites-available/* -

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

To finish off, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, Everything here is supposed to run on localhost, I just wanted to play around with reverse proxy to see if I like it or not.

Any clue what I've screwed up here?

-- I actually figured this out, I hadn't allowed directory access to the proper directory in Apache, so it would respond to nginx with a 403.

Comment: Have you checked port 8080 is open or not ?

Comment: Default nginx web folder is : /var/www/html because you have set : proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

Comment: Have you checked the nginx error log? You may find more details there.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan yes apache is still listening on 8080.

Comment: @ColeTierney, yeah I thought that, when I checked it yielded the same information I knew. example below:

2016/03/28 21:32:21 [error] 912#0: *7 directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Comment: If there's no index file in /var/www, you'll get directory index forbidden unless you specify `autoindex on`. I see nginx and apache have different roots. Is that intentional?

Comment: @ColeTierney thanks for catching that, now they match. After restarting the services nginx runs fine, but apache returns the same error though.